# Chaining promise in loops

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm facing a complicated promise chain and it looks like the results doesn't wait for the end of the promise.

```
return Promise.all([
  Radar.newRadar(1),
  Radar.newRadar(2),
  Radar.newRadar(3)
])
.then( newRadarIds => {
    let RadarNotes = [];
  return Promise.all([
     _.map(newRadarIds, (radar_id) =>{
      return Promise.all([
        Radar.init(radar_id)
      ])
      .then( kpis => {
        return Promise.all([
          Radar.addKpis(radar_id.radar_id, ...)
        ])
        .then( radarAddKpi => {
          RadarNotes.push({
            year : radar_id.year,
            data : kpis[0].data});
            console.log('in map')
          // return {
          //   year : radar_id.year,
          //   data : kpis[0].data}
        })
        .catch( err => {
          console.error(err);
        })
      })

    }) //end map
  ])
  .then(result => {
    console.log('her222e')
    res.json(result)
  })
  .catch (err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  })
.catch( error => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

I get the output 'here' before the 'in map'. The goal is to fill an array and send it to the client with a `res.json` call.

What am I missing ?

Comment: does `Radar.init(radar_id)` return a promise? how about `Radar.addKpis(radar_id.radar_id, ...)` does that return a promise?

Comment: `Radar.addKpis(radar_id.radar_id, ...)` looks funky on it's own, let alone inside a `Promise.all([])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is

```
return Promise.all([
  _.map(newRadarIds, (radar_id) =>{
    return // a promise
  }) //end map
])
```

which calls `Promise.all` on an array *of arrays* of promises. Which wont be awaited. You will want to drop the array literal and pass the result of the `map` - the array of promises - directly to `Promise.all`.

---

Also calling `Promise.all([ … ])` with a single-element array (`Radar.init`, `Radar.addKpis`) is pretty superfluous (and potentially harmful if you don't expect the result to be an array). Just chain the `then` directly to the promise you have.

Finally, your `result` will consist of `undefined` entries, as your promises don't resolve with anything. You would need to send the `RadarNotes` explicitly. But better than pushing to that array is to fulfill your promises with each result, so that `Promise.all` can construct the promise for the array of all results:

```
return Promise.all([
  Radar.newRadar(1),
  Radar.newRadar(2),
  Radar.newRadar(3)
])
.then(newRadarIds =>
  Promise.all(_.map(newRadarIds, radar_id =>
    Radar.init(radar_id)
    .then(kpi =>
      Radar.addKpis(radar_id.radar_id, ...)
      .then(radarAddKpi =>
        ({
          year : radar_id.year,
          data : kpi.data
        })
      )
    )
  ))
)
.then(result => {
  res.json(result)
})
.catch (err => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I was just going to comment on that :-) They don't cause an unexpected execution order though

Comment: true, removed the comment :p